# php não reconhece o id para edição do metodo get

Tags: php, html, mysql

estou fazendo um codigo simples de manipulação de banco de dados, porem na parte de editar o cod simplesmente nao consegue reconhecer o id a qual quero editar, se caso eu coloco o id na condição manualmente ele edita normalmente, algum erro que não estou vendo? segue as duas pags de cod

pagina de inserção:

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>clinica</title>


</head>

<body>

<form>
    <h4>convenios</h4>
    digite aqui seu nome:<br>
    <input type="text" name="nome" ><br>
    digite aqui numero de contato:<br>
    <input type="number" name="numero" ><br>
    <input type="submit" name="ok">


</form>

<table border="1">
<ul>
<?php 
$con = new PDO("mysql:dbname=atividade4;host=localhost:3307;","root", "");

if (isset($_GET['excluir'])) {
    $id=(int)$_GET['excluir'];
    $con->exec("delete from convenios where id=$id");
}

if (isset($_GET['nome'])) {
    

$ins = $con -> prepare("insert into convenios values (DEFAULT,'".$_GET['nome']."','".$_GET['numero']."')");
$ins -> execute();
}

$mostrar = $con -> prepare("select * from convenios");



$mostrar -> execute();



$dados = $mostrar -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


echo "<tr>
<td> id</td>
<td> nome</td>
<td> numero</td>
<td> excluir</td>
<td> editar</td>
</tr>";

 foreach ($dados as $key => $value) {
    echo "<tr>".
    "<td>". $value['id'] ."</td>".
    "<td>". $value['nome'] ."</td>".
    "<td>". $value['telefone'] ."</td> <td>
<a href='?excluir=".$value['id']."'>Excluir </a>
</td>
<td>
<a href='editarconv.php?id=".$value['id']."'>editar </a>
</td>

    ".
    

    "</tr>";
 

}

?> 




  
  
    



</body>

</html> ```


pagina de edição:

       ``` <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Convênios</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Formulário </h1>
    Digite as novas informações:
    <?php 
        $con = new PDO("mysql:dbname=atividade4;host=localhost:3307;","root", "");

        $stm = $con -> prepare("select * from convenios where id='".$_GET['id']."';");
        $stm -> execute();
        $dados = $stm -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        ?>

        <form method='get' action=''>
                Nome: <input type='text' name='nome' value="<?php echo $dados[0]['nome']; ?> "><br><br>
                Telefone: <input type='text' name='telefone' value="<?php echo $dados[0]['telefone']; ?> "><br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="editar" value="Editar"></form>
    <?php 

        if (isset($_GET['editar'])) {
            

        $con = new PDO("mysql:dbname=atividade4;host=localhost:3307;","root", "");

        $stm = $con ->prepare("update convenios set nome ='".$_GET['nome']."', telefone ='".$_GET['telefone']."' where id='".$_GET['id']."';");
        $stm -> execute();
        $dados = $stm -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        header("location:convenio.php");
    
        }
        ?>


</body>
</html>
````

Answer (score -1):

O teu formulário não tem nenhum campo com o id, tens que acrescentar.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $dados[0]['id']; ?>">
```